# Does eating egg for Sehri makes Roza makrooh?

Tags: hadith, makruh

A shopkeeper who sells egg doesn't give me egg saying that it makes Roza as Makrooh.
And other person said that if you are eating egg then it should be break with some dua else it will Makrooh my fast.

Please any one can provide reference to it.
Jazak Allah

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not makrooh to take eggs in Sahar time. You can eat it.

Normally, egg is one of the wind producing food. It might get uneasy during fasting for some people. So, they avoid these types of food. Foods with complex carbohydrates and protein like Haleem, Dates, Almonds, Bananas are highly recommended during Sahar time. But, these are things about good health and nutrition, islam doesn't forbid foods like egg to take in Sahar.

There is no specific dua for breaking egg to make it non-makrooh. We should say Bismillah before doing anything. So, if you ask for the dua before breaking egg, `Bismillah` is that dua. And please keep in mind that if you forget to say bismillah before breaking egg, it will not affect your fast.

Comment: What about egg if it is broken without saying dua of breaking egg??

Comment: any thing that is halal can be eaten by muslim anytime be it iftaar,seher,dinner,lunch .